# Terminal is not sourcing .bash_profile, but sourcing .profile

Tags: macos, maven, bash, .profile

I created a .bash_profile and added the following:

**export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
export M2_HOME=/Users/aastha/apache-maven-3.3.9
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin**

When I check echo $PATH, I get the following
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
(i.e) maven path is not imported.
and also mvn -version shows: mvn:command not found

When I manually source using source ~/.bash_profile and then do echo $PATH, I am able to see correct mvn path that I have entered in PATH variable in .bash_profile.
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/aastha/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin

mvn -version shows:
**Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T22:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: /Users/aastha/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"**

*My terminal does not source .bash_profile until I manually source it using
source ~/.bash_profile
Note: I created a .profile with the similar content and found out in this case mvn -version shows the maven is installed. And terminal is sourcing .profile automatically.
Why is my terminal not able to source .bash_profile automatically*

Could somebody please help? 
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Also note when same content is added to .profile , I could see that echo $PATH shows correct path and men -version shows that maven is installed

Comment: Just to be sure... Are you using bash as shell interpreter? You can find it out running: ps -p $$

Comment: when I tried ps -p $$ –  I got the the following as output                               ps: illegal argument: –
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-g grp[,grp...]] [-u [uid,uid...]]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]                                               
       ps [-L]                                           I am not sure what this command does.. FYI I am trying this out on Mac terminal

Comment: Also though I am able to check the version of maven installed using mvn -version , my Xcode project still shows the error :    mvn:command not found  . Do I need to change some build settings in Xcode also?

Comment: The command to find out which shell you are using is without the final dash: `ps -p $$`